# Query "disjointed" Android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working with a sqlite database in android whose entity-relationship diagram is as follows:
[image: Database diagram]

What I'm trying to do is to query and return in a cursor all columns from the vehicle_implement table and all tables to its left, joining via the foreign keys depicted in the diagram. In vehicle_implement there are some null implement_ids, and I still want those rows. There aren't, and won't be, any null vehicle_ids. I think that it may not be possible to return anything from the tables to the left of the implement table when implement_id is null, which prevents me from getting all of the columns and rows I want.

I think that this wouldn't be difficult to do using temporary tables, but I'm trying to do this using queryBuilder. I'm open to doing it without queryBuilder if I can still return my results in a cursor from queries to the content provider that fronts the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join).

Comment: I am familiar with outer joins. I thought I was more constrained by QuerbyBuilder in terms of the format of acceptable queries than is actually the case. A coworker figured out a solution, and I will post it. One lesson learned is to try to get a solution without assuming constraints, try it, and let the results indicate whether and what constraints are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vehicle_implement

LEFT JOIN vehicle ON vehicle_implement.vehicle_id = vehicle._id

LEFT JOIN implement ON vehicle_implement.implement_id = implement._id

LEFT JOIN vehicle_model ON vehicle.vehicle_model_id = vehicle_model._id

LEFT JOIN vehicle_type ON vehicle_model.vehicle_type_id = vehicle_type._id

LEFT JOIN implement_model ON implement.implement_model_id = implement_model._id

LEFT JOIN implement_type ON implement_model.implement_type_id = implement_type._id

LEFT JOIN operation_implement_type ON implement_type._id = operation_implement_type.implement_type_id

LEFT JOIN operation ON operation_implement_type.operation_id = operation._id`